# How do I set up multiple conditions on Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to set up some conditions on Thymeleaf templates like this,
but it doesn't work.

```
<li th:if="${entry.description != null && entry.owner == true}" th:each="entry : ${entryList}" class="group">
```

How do I make this code correctly work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace

```
"${entry.description != null && entry.owner == true}"
```

with

```
"${entry.description != null and entry.owner == true}"
```

For reference you can check out this thread:
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-have-multiple-condition-in-an-th-if-tag-td4025931.html

Let me know how you go

Comment: Aeseir,

thank you for answering my question.
I could solve the problem by your answer.
your quick answer really helped me.
thank you.

Comment: @ryokato: You could improve this even further by using the `eq`, `lt`, `gt` etc. class of [aliases](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html) for comparisons, *e.g.*: `"${entry.description ne null and entry.owner eq true}"`. Personally, I don't like using the raw operators if the plain-text representations are also available (although I guess that's a matter of taste).